# Calculate object position irrespective of camera orientation in augmented reality

Tags: ios, camera, computer-vision, augmented-reality

Recently I am working on a game in iOS and trying to get a feature like Pokemon Go game where an object stays in a specific position and trying to find this object by camera view.

So, I read some tutorial and got some help from these articles:

[Augmented Reality Tutorial for iOS from Ray Wenderlich Blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/augmented-reality-tutorial-for-ios)
 [Augmented Reality iOS Tutorial: Location Based from Ray Wenderlich Blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/42266/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based)

From this tutorial I successfully completed to find object from camera view only in one device orientation. i.e. Only Landscape Left & Landscape Right are working but when I rotate my device from landscape to portrait, object runs away and can't see in camera when I pointing to that same position.

**My problem**: How can I calculate position for an Object irrespective of different camera orientation like landscape to portrait and vice versa? What is the mathematical calculation for handling this in different orientation??

Comment: Please ask if there is anything that I need to clarify more, or any way in which I can improve the question. I urgently need to know this. I would have set bounty on it immediately if I could, but I have to for 2 days :-(

Answer (score 1):

the thing is pretty easy from mathematical point of view. To achieve that you need to know where the object is in real world. For example you need to have GPS coordinates of the virtual object. Based on that you need to get the azimuth of this location.
The next step is to count on which azimuth the user is looking through the camera. Calculate it in degrees so you will have a result <0, 360)

When you have both results you need to check if the azimuth you're looking is in your field of view.
For example if we assume that you`re looking at azimuth 0 and your field of view is 180 degrees than you see everything from in <90, 0), <0, 270>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please can you provide me implementation or tutorial link?? need elaborate explanation.

Comment: No, I don't have anything like this. I wrote suche code some time ago. It deprnds on The Technology you aren using.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: @SakibAhammed if the answer is valuable than upvote it so someone else whom will look for something similar will know